# Probability finite precision Random Matrix has distinct eigenvalues

Tags: probability, matrices, random-matrices

There is a theorem which says the probability/size of a random matrix having repeated eigenvalues is 0 and this result is used in many fields. What I am wondering is, how does this translate to real systems with finite precision?

How can we extend this result to make some statement on the probability a random matrix with finite precision has no repeat eigenvalues? Obviously it's no longer 0 but how do we quantify it?

Comment: A rough estimate is to ask about eigenvalues that are near zero, and then see if an $O(precision)$ perturbation of the matrix ( representing the roundoff) can set the eigenvalue to zero.

Comment: Coming to think of a practical example, one technique to deal with linear systems which have repeated eigenvalues is choosing a random feedback matrix which removes the repeatedness. At first glance it seems like a good idea! But without further investigation this technique obviously may be unsound.

Comment: crossposted at https://mathoverflow.net/q/388871/11260